# "No persistence unit with name 'product' found"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, tomcat, jpa

I recently completed this tutorial: "http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/", but now I want it to work with Hibernate and annotations. I know I'm close but I've hit a roadblock and I can't figure it out. I've posted my code on the Spring forums [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=337775&posted=1#post337775). I would greatly appreciate ANY help. Thanks

I'm trying to incorporate annotations and hibernate into it, but I've run into a problem and I can't figure it out. I keep getting errors of "No persistence unit with name 'product' found". ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: next time don't title your question "technology1 / technology2 help". It does not tell anything about the problem

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need a `META-INF/persistence.xml`, with `<persistence-unit name="product">`. [See here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging)

(I usually put it in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`. As noted in the comments, with maven you can place it in `src/main/resources/META-INF`)

Comment: Sean Patrick Floyd is right: at least the persistence.xml have to be located at \WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml (for an standard web application) -- In normal case you reach this goal if you put the persistence.xml in the META-INF directory of you java sources directory. (If you use maven than put it in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml.)

Comment: sorry, corrected. I usually put it in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` though

Comment: I already have persistance.xml... when I created it, I also created the META-INF folder. The WEB-INF folder was created when I went through the tutorial. Thanks

Comment: @type7 - and..? The problem should be resolved if the xml is in the correct location. Show it to us

Comment: ahhh... putting META-INF into the classes folder worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Bozho is there a way to use custom location of persistence.xml? (i'd like to place it right in resources/ folder and still have it discovered by spring)

Answer (score 2):

this is a example of file persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="poduct"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

create this file inside "**src/main/resources/META-INF**" if you use Maven project.

Answer (score 2):

I run onto the same problem and had to manually edit the Web Deployment Assembly Configuration so as to instruct `/META-INF/persistence.xml` to be deployed under `WEB-INF/classes/` (the red box in the attached [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZq4I.png) was manually edited)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with us. added `META-INF` in `classes` will solve my issue. +1

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem. But when you use the ide(for example eclipse) and configure your server in the ide. When you asosiate the piece and restart the server always have the same error because detected the persistence unit is used, you need delete that part of the server and deploy to the oldway. Enter to the console and install the peace of you project and works!!

And the other is when you check the diagnostic in wls you need said who user is the owner of the jdbc, only select and check (for example, AdminServer) and save and check again!!

:D

Comment: This isn't very clear to me. Could you provide specific steps? Also, what differentiates your answer from the other answers already provided? Maybe this is more appropriate as a comment?